# Cuándo usar sigprocmask?

Tags: c, unix

En el desarrollo del código tengo `sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask,NULL)`, entonces cuando se hace un `fork()`:

- ¿el hijo hereda las señales bloqueadas o desbloqueadas?
- ¿Es necesario usar `sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL)` para desbloquearlas al usar el proceso hijo?

Comment: Según la documentación, debería heredar la máscara de señales. ¿Has probado y no es así?

Comment: Tuve un error acabo de corregirlo, ahor alo hereda, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, efectivamente, en caso de que el `sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask,NULL)` se encuentre antes de la sentencia `fork()` el proceso hijo hereda las señales bloqueadas o desbloqueadas.

Puedes consultar la información en el manual de programación de Linux, acá te dejo el enlace de

[SIGPROCMASK](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html)

En el apartado de NOTAS hacen referencia a la llamada al sistema `fork()`.
Saludos.

Comment: Gracias chicos un saludo

Comment: @inoshita Si esta respuesta te sirve, deberias marcarla como aceptada